# Force external app launched via startActivity to go back to my app

Tags: android, android-intent

The app I'm developing will launch the default SMS app available on the user's device. For this, I call `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:123456"))`. The SMS app opens correctly, but I see inconsistent behavior when the user pushes the back button:

- On an emulator running Android 7, the control is brought back to my app, as expected.
- On an emulator running Android 6, the back button performs an "up" action and I'm now on the SMS messages list. If I push back again, I go to the home screen, and I had to relaunch my app.

For me as an user, the behavior in Android 6 is unexpected. If app A launches app B, pushing back should always go back to app A, regardless of app B implementing the "up" action or not.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to specify, in the intent data/flags, that the back button pushed in the started activity will bring the user back the "starter" activity.

I've tried using `startActivityForResult` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is usually controllable via Intent flags, e.g. something like:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

Should behave as expected.

It seems that this in this case, this is not system/intent behavior, it might be specific to the messaging app you're using.

When testing on OnePlus one/Android M, I get the two different scenarios if I'm using the `Messaging` app as the default sms app, or when using `Google Messages` app from Google Play.

Looking a bit into the first scenario where back button goes back to the main activity of the external SMS app, I see the following lines in `LogCat`:

```
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=sms:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10808000 cmp=com.android.messaging/.ui.conversation.LaunchConversationActivity
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.android.messaging/.ui.conversationlist.ConversationListActivity}
ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.messaging/.ui.conversation.ConversationActivity
ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.messaging/.ui.conversation.ConversationActivity
```

This means that the activity that is listed for the `SENDTO` action is `LaunchConversationActivity`, which calls `startActivity` on its own to the `ConversationListActivity` and then opens in the same task `ConversationActivity`, so the back button goes back to the SMS main Activity, and not yours.